# Thunderbird login screen cannot select next or more options

Tags: 16.04, email, thunderbird, gmail

I am setting up Thunderbird on Ubuntu 16.04.2, when trying to log in with any gmail based account. When logging in a browser windows opens with a field for "email or phone" as well as two buttons "More options" and "Next". Selecting "Next" or "More Options" does not do anything, neither does pressing "enter" rendering me unable to log in. Is there a way around this issue?
[image]

Comment: Do you happen to have 2 factor auth enabled in gmail? just a guess.

Comment: I do, yes. I have a generated key, but I have not seen a place to put it in yet.

Comment: Although I have the same issue with my other gmail account that does not have 2 factor auth turned on.

Comment: I avoid gmail like the plague, so I am just taking a guess here.

Comment: a screenshot might help as well...

Comment: I just added one!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this results due to a change in Google's login front-end. It's fixed in the latest TB, but for Ubuntu you should wait for the package maintainer if you are only using official repos. For more details and possible workarounds:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1359297